# Is it safe to use _MSVC_LANG instead of __cplusplus?

Tags: c++11, visual-c++

I am trying to compile a multiplatform C++ project with the Microsoft Visual C++ compiler (formerly the GCC was used, among other compilers).

Now I come across some preprocessor directives like this one:

```
#if __cplusplus < 201103L
    // Define some macros of C++11 the code really relies on.
    // [...]
#endif
```

Although I use Visual Studio 2015, `__cplusplus` is still defined as `199711L`. [This post from the Microsoft blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/06/07/standards-version-switches-in-the-compiler/) advises to check also for `_MSVC_LANG`.

To what extent does `_MSVC_LANG >= 201402L` not comply with C++11 ?

Comment: Check *also*, not *instead* (logical or).

Comment: Ok, I've edited it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, if you want a portable workaround, you can do:

```
#if __cplusplus < 201103L && _MSVC_LANG < 201103L
/* ... */
#elif __cplusplus >= 201402L || _MSVC_LANG >= 201402L
```

The comment you link states that it’s a bug that `__cplusplus` is not set correctly and that testing `_MSVC_LANG` is a stopgap.  However, VC 2017 (19.10.25017) with `/std:c++14` still sets `__cplusplus` to `199711`.

The `_MSVC_LANG` macro is a Microsoft extension.  Most other compilers do not set it, to make it easier to test that the compiler is or is not Microsoft.  (One exception: `clang++ --std:c++14 -fms-compatibility-version=19.10` will set both `__cplusplus` and `_MSVC_LANG` to `201402L`, as that is its MSVC compatibility mode.)  On other compilers, it should expand to `0`.

**ETA:** Thanks to an anonymous commenter for pointing out that there is a  `/Zc:__cplusplus` compiler switch, which sets the value of `__cplusplus` to the same as `_MSVC_LANG`.  MSVC 19 does not change the version of `__cplusplus` without this flag, as apparently that broke existing code.

Comment: Relevant: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/zc-cplusplus