# C2386: 'void_t': a symbol with this name already exists in the current scope

Tags: c++, cmake, visual-studio-2017, c++14

I'm working on a **Qt** project which is intended to be built on **Windows** and on **Linux**. As a build system I use **CMake** with GCC 5.4 on Ubuntu 16.04 and with Visual Studio 2017 on Windows 10. Because the currently used standard is [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14) but I wanted to use the convenience type [`std::void_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/void_t) I defined it as follows:

```cpp
#if __cplusplus >= 201703L
#include <type_traits>
#else
namespace std {
template<typename... Ts> struct make_void { typedef void type; };
template<typename... Ts> using void_t = typename make_void<Ts...>::type;
}
#endif
```

The definition above is working fine if I build the project under Linux with the mentioned compiler, but when I try to build it under Windows I receive the following error messages:

```
C2386: 'void_t': a symbol with this name already exists in the current scope
U1077: 'C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~4\2017\ENTERP~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1411~1.255\bin\HostX64\x64\cl.exe' : return code '0x2'
U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\bin\HostX64\x64\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\bin\HostX64\x64\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
```

The top-level CMake file sets the C++ standard as follows:

```cmake
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)
```

I don't understand why does Visual Studio 2017 complain for the `std::void_t` when the standard is set to [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14). Is this a normal behaviour and I expect it incorrectly that polluting the `std` namespace in the shown way won't cause errors? How can I overcome these errors produced by the Visual Studio 2017?

---

**Edit:** I just noticed that relying on the value of predefined macro `__cplusplus` may cause [unexpected results](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/139261/msvc-incorrectly-defines-cplusplus.html). [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43639322/7893951) question also aims to the `__cplusplus` macro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.10/prop_tgt/CXX_STANDARD.html#prop_tgt:CXX_STANDARD) option currently has limited effect on Visual Studio.

Unlike gcc or clang, which offer the `-std` command line switches for specifying the requested version of the Standard, Visual C++ used to always give you all the latest features at once. Only with the 2015 version (Update 3) did they introduce a [`/std` option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/std-specify-language-standard-version) that is intended to provide an opt-in mechanism for newer language features.

Unfortunately, this is not as mature yet as the gcc or clang equivalents, so you might still get features that you would not have expected.

Answer (score 4):

> Is this a normal behaviour and I expect it incorrectly that polluting the std namespace in the shown way won't cause errors?

The standard library owns `namespace std` - you are only allowed to add things to it in certain, specific situations. Declaring brand new types is not one of those situations, and you should just not do it. Polluting `namespace std` is asking for trouble at some point.

In this particular case, there's really nothing to lose by using your own `void_t` over the standard library version. It'll work. So just do that. Or if you really want to use the standard ones, bring one or the other into a different namespace:

```
namespace xstd {
#if __cplusplus >= 201703L
    using std::void_t;
#else    
    template<typename... Ts> struct make_void { typedef void type; };
    template<typename... Ts> using void_t = typename make_void<Ts...>::type;
#endif
}

// use xstd::void_t throughout
```